# XQuery for selecting and grouping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery-sql

I am trying to export some information out of an xml column.

Logic applied:
In each part, the actor Name may appear twice.
(actor + song) result to a unique combination.

Keep only when at aggregation level, scene=1. We don't care about scene=2.
We care about the lines for specific actors.
Simba, Mufasa and Zazu.
Let's not worry about Scar. He is mean.
My expected output is:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4T4v.png)

My T-Sql code so far:
I have managed to filter out the aggregate level = 2.

Could somebody assist?

```
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE (Information xml)
INSERT INTO @Temp SELECT @x;
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('lyceum' AS ns1)
SELECT
    Z.query('ns1:feature')
FROM @Temp
CROSS APPLY Information.nodes('/ns1:report/ns1:detail/ns1:parts/ns1:part') AS Y(Z)
WHERE Z.exist('ns1:aggregation[.="1"]') = 1
```

Below you can find the xml in order to have something easily reproducible:

```
DECLARE @x as xml;
set @x = '<ns1:report xmlns:ns1="lyceum">
    <ns1:header>
        <ns1:report>The Lion King</ns1:report>
    </ns1:header>
    <ns1:detail>
        <ns1:parts>
            <ns1:part>
                <ns1:aggregation>
                    <ns1:scene>1</ns1:scene>
                </ns1:aggregation>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Simba</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>100</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>1</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Mufasa</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>200</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>1</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Simba</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>300</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>2</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Zazu</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>400</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>2</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Scar</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>500</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>2</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
            </ns1:part>
            <ns1:part>
                <ns1:aggregation>
                    <ns1:scene>2</ns1:scene>
                </ns1:aggregation>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Simba</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>600</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>1</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Mufasa</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>700</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>1</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Simba</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>800</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>2</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Zazu</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>900</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>2</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Scar</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>1000</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>2</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
            </ns1:part>
        </ns1:parts>
    </ns1:detail>
</ns1:report>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for XQuery to select and group: Try this:

A *mockup table* to simulate your issue:

```sql
DECLARE @Temp AS TABLE (Information xml);
INSERT @Temp VALUES
('<ns1:report xmlns:ns1="lyceum">
    <ns1:header>
        <ns1:report>The Lion King</ns1:report>
    </ns1:header>
    <ns1:detail>
        <ns1:parts>
            <ns1:part>
                <ns1:aggregation>
                    <ns1:scene>1</ns1:scene>
                </ns1:aggregation>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Simba</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>100</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>1</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Mufasa</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>200</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>1</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Simba</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>300</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>2</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Zazu</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>400</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>2</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
                <ns1:feature>
                    <ns1:actor>Scar</ns1:actor>
                    <ns1:lines>500</ns1:lines>
                    <ns1:song>2</ns1:song>
                </ns1:feature>
            </ns1:part>
            <ns1:part>
                <ns1:aggregation>
                    <ns1:scene>2</ns1:scene>
                </ns1:aggregation>
                <ns1:feature>
<!-- shortened for brevity -->
                </ns1:feature>
            </ns1:part>
        </ns1:parts>
    </ns1:detail>
</ns1:report>');
```

--The query

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('lyceum' AS ns1)
SELECT p.query('<root>
                {
                    for $s in distinct-values(ns1:feature/ns1:song/text())
                    return <song scene="{$s}">
                        {
                        for $f in ns1:feature[ns1:song[text()=$s]]
                        return
                        if($f/ns1:actor/text() != "Scar") then
                            <actor name="{$f/ns1:actor/text()}" lines="{$f/ns1:lines/text()}"/>
                        else
                            ()
                        }
                    </song>
                }
                </root>')
  
FROM @Temp t
CROSS APPLY t.Information.nodes('/ns1:report/ns1:detail/ns1:parts/ns1:part[(ns1:aggregation/ns1:scene/text())[1]="1"]') A(p);
```

The result

```sql
<root>
  <song scene="1">
    <actor name="Simba" lines="100" />
    <actor name="Mufasa" lines="200" />
  </song>
  <song scene="2">
    <actor name="Simba" lines="300" />
    <actor name="Zazu" lines="400" />
  </song>
</root>
```

The idea in short:

- We us a predicate in `.nodes()` to return the part(s) where `<scene>`=1
- We use `.query()` to return a newly created XML
- We add (might be omitted) a `<root>` node
- We add a FLWOR query running through a distinct-list of song ids
- We use this song id in another FLOWR query as predicate to filter the fitting `<feature>` elements
- We check for the actor's name not being "Scar"

The output you are asking for is an entirely different problem.
Using **content** as column name demands either for knowing all expected names in advance (`PIVOT` or *conditional aggregation*) or to use dynamically created statements.

Comment: Thank you @Shnugo. You are right about the expected output on my question. It is a different problem indeed.